# Connect two tables with help of an another table -- MySQL join

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables `first` `second` and `f_s` which connects two tables together as shown below

```
first_id │  first            second_id │ second         first_id │ second_id
   1       station               1       address            1       1 
   2       hospital              2        point             1       2 
   3       hotel                                            2       1
                                                            2       2
                                                            3       1
```

I want `second.second_id` and `second.second` for a given `first.first`. How should i write mySQL query?

**Example:** `station` is given:

```
first  │ second_id│  second
station      1       address
station      2       point
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be a simple join of three tables.

```
 SELECT * from first f join f_s fs on f.first_id=fs.first_id join second s on fs.second_id=s.second_id;
```